# How to query Maya in script for supported file translator plugins?

Tags: maya, mel, pymel

I'm trying to specify an FBX file in MEL using the command
   file -f -pmt 0 -options "v=0;" -typ "FBX" -o

on one computer this works great. On another, it fails but DOES work if I use
    -typ "Fbx"

I think I'd like to query for the supported translators in my script, then either select the correct one or report an error.  Is this possible? Am I mis-diagnosing the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MEL has a command called pluginInfo. You could write a simple function that will return the proper spelling based on that. `pluginInfo -v -query "fbxmaya";` will provide the version of the fbx plugin. I haven't used MEL in a while so I'm not gonna try to make this perfect but maybe something like `if(pluginInfo -v -query "fbxmaya") ) string fbxType = "FBX" else( string fbxType = "Fbx")`. Then just plug that var into `file -f -pmt 0 -options "v=0;" -typ $fbxType -o`.

Comment: I couldn't fit all that into the comment box :P

Comment: One interesting thing that I noticed is that if you set the file dialog to "Os Native" you will get a different answer from fbxmaya in Maya 2014.

Answer (score 0):

It might be a different version of fbx. You'd have to provide another line which determines the version of fbx on that particular machine and pipes in the correct spelling.

Comment: I'm experimenting with things like  if( catch( `file -typ "FBX"`) ...   but that seems kinda brute force. What did you have in mind that could determine an FBX version?? iterating the plugins somehow??

Comment: MEL has a command called pluginInfo. You could write a simple function that will return the proper spelling based on that. `pluginInfo -v -query "fbxmaya";` will provide the version of the fbx plugin.